# How to infer function overloading TS Types, when args are functions with optional args

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading

I want to implement a pattern similar to `React.useState()`. Basically, the function would accept one of 2 things:

- A {string} value to update the state to.
- A {function} that accepts the previousState and produces a new one.

Here is an example not that complex. The interface din:

```js
interface OverloadedFn<TArgs>  {
    (args: TArgs): void;
    (setter: (args: TArgs) => TArgs): void;
}

const overloadedFn: OverloadedFn<{ arg1: number }> = (arg) => {
    if (typeof arg === 'function') {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
}
```

I can write the overload, with multiple function, with type or with interface, but the args, will never get typed. I even removed the Generic. Any ideas?

```
TS7006: Parameter 'arg' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example, in TS Playgound: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIDdoBsD2cAmE+AYiADwAqAglAOYDOAfMgN4CwAUMsgBRx30AXMmoCAlMPpgooWgG5O3HvQhhIUYXwHDRDMcgC8zXfQnIpMkPM4BfTpwQ4QU5DkxRcBIqWEZseQhJyFmR+WgBGYRAAVwBbACNoZBtmA14w00Nmdi5kYBheMABPAAcIHAKMwwM0gHIYaJAEMGAnWv0c7i7kKFVoqBBkWvDaxWTkCCwVVjHu3rB+wdqAJlHcuw4bOSA

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/w11dlw). Could you try to make sure you're providing a [mre]?  Maybe you're not using a recent enough version of TypeScript, but if that's the case then such information should be part of the question. Good luck!

Comment: I am using 4.1.5. I will make a TS Playground and update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the response nonetheless.

Comment: And it seem that in 4.2+ I get the `Types` pretty nicely. But not in `4.1.5`. Thanks! Will close the question. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Looks like this works in the ts playground if you use 4.3.5+. Are you in a position to just upgrade?

Comment: Not immediately. But will have to, as I need to use it in a few places, in the very near future. Thanks!